# Javascript - show hidden table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm brand new to Javascript, and need some help.  I have a table with 4 rows (3 displayed, and 1 display="none").  What I'm trying to do is display the 4th row via clicking on a link.  Here's what my HTML looks like:

```
<table class="lessons">
  <tr>
    <td class="chapter">01</td>
    <td class="title-desc"><h3 class="title">INTRODUCTION TO PROGRAM</h3>
      <h3 class="desc">Program description....blah blah blah...</h3>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="chapter">02</td>
    <td class="title-desc"><h3 class="title">PARTNER WITH THE PROGRAM</h3>
      <h3 class="desc">Description for chapter 2....blah blah...blah...</h3>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="chapter">03</td>
    <td class="title-desc"><h3 class="title">FOCUS ON THE PROGRAM</h3>
      <h3 class="desc">Description for chapter 3...blah blah blah....</h3>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hiddenRow" style="display:none;">
    <td class="chapter">04</td>
    <td class="title-desc"><h3 class="title">THIS CHAPTER IS HIDDEN</h3>
      <h3 class="desc">Chapter four description....blah blah...</h3>
  </tr>

</table>
<a href="javascript:showRows();">show hidden</a>
```

And here's my javascript:

```
function showRows(){
 var thisRow = document.getElementsByClassName('hiddenRow');
  thisRow.style.display="";
}
```

Link to JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/99600cha/

I've tried doing the javascript function a few different ways with no success.  Could someone show me what I'm doing wrong?

What I'm really trying to do is have the first and last rows displayed with the middle rows hidden and expandable, like this:

Chapter 1

(click to see all chapters)

Chapter 10

so if anyone can point me to something similar, please do!

Edit:  Here is a link that shows the exact effect I'm trying to accomplish: https://www.masterclass.com/classes/aaron-sorkin-teaches-screenwriting

Answer (score 0):

if your are using jquery:

```
function showRows(){
$('.hiddenRow').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `var thisRow = document.getElementsByClassName('hiddenRow');` `thisRow` returns an array of elements that have such class, you have to use `thisRow[0]` to select a first element.

However, a more elegant and cleaner solution would be making this layout:

```
<div class="lessons" id="lessons">
     <div class="lesson">
        <div class="chapter">01</div>
        <div class="title">...</div>
        <div class="whatever">...</div>
        <div class="whatever">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="lesson">
        <div class="chapter">01</div>
        <div class="title">...</div>
        <div class="whatever">...</div>
        <div class="whatever">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="lesson-hidden">
        <div class="chapter">A hidden lesson.</div>
        <div class="title">...</div>
        <div class="whatever">...</div>
        <div class="whatever">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

By using this simple CSS rule you will be able to hide all elements by changing a single class:

```
.lessons .lesson-hidden { display: none; }
.lessons.full .lesson-hidden { display: block; }
```

To show hidden lessons, use this line:
`document.getElementById("lessons").classList.add("full")`
To revert, use this line: `document.getElementById("lessons").classList.remove("full")`

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Like I said, I am very new to HTML, CSS, Javascript.  Could you maybe provide me a link to a little more detail on how to do this?  or perhaps a working example?  The exact effect I'm going for here is this: [Chapter Listing](https://www.masterclass.com/classes/aaron-sorkin-teaches-screenwriting)

Comment: Thank You!  Exactly what I was going for!

Comment: @Lost_in_C_space Make sure to accept this answer. No problem!